# Swift: Presenting a viewController over UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, uitabbarcontroller

After my app is finished launching, I want my app to open a `LoginViewController` if a current user is not logged in. Otherwise, it goes to a `ViewController` which is at the index of 0 (default value). So if not logged in, then show a modal view over `UITabBarController`.

My initial viewcontroller is a `UITabBarController`, which is created in `UIStoryboard`. It is check-marked as `Initial View` and is connected to other five viewcontrollers graphically.

Actually, I think I know the reason why a `LoginViewController` does not appear. It is because the value result was nil (I checked in the console). But why?? Other than this behavior, everything is working well. `UITabBarController` seems to be working without any problem.

My `LoginViewController` is embedded with `UINavigationViewController`. This code is inside a `ViewController` which is at a selected index of 0. It is put inside `viewDidAppear()` method

```
 let main = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 let view = main.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "login") as! LoginViewController
 let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: view)
 self.tabBarController?.present(nav, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

However, it is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the **rootViewController** of window to **UINavigationController** if user is not logged in and if he is change it to the **tabBarController**

Comment: Hey man it is working as I expected!! Thanks so much. Your answer is the perfect answer!! 

Comment: But When I do this, it affects my viewcontrollers inside UITabViewController. these controllers do not need UINavigation.

Comment: I know after login finishes change the root to the tabbar

Comment: Oh thanks. I worked! I did it in ApplicationDidFinishLaunching.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement the logic of deciding what is the desired initial view controller to be the root (based on whether the user logged in or not) *before* navigating to any view controller, [application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application) method would be appropriate for such an implementation:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    // let's assume that you are recognizing if the user logged in by a flag called 'isLoggedin':

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    if isLoggedin { // show display main view controller
        let mainViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "mainViewController")
        // setup any needed config for mainViewController...
        self.window?.rootViewController = mainViewController
    } else { // display login view controller
        let loginViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginViewController")
         // setup any needed config for loginViewController...
        self.window?.rootViewController = loginViewController
    }

    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

Or as a shorter version:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let isLoggedin = false

    let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: isLoggedin ? "mainViewController" : "loginViewController")
    self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

    return true
}
```

At this point, after the app finished launching (without jumping to any view controller yet), the initial view controller would be displayed based on the user logging in validation. I would assume that it would be a better behavior unless there is a *specific requirement* to present the login view controller on the of the tabbar controller; Logically, there is no even need to navigate to the tabbar controller if the user didn't login yet.

Comment: But how do you access UITabBarViewController when it is only instanciated in UIStoryboard and I did not make any subclass? It is working fine without subclassing. In this case, how do you write code in appDidFinishLaunching?

Comment: @RyoheiArai Just click on your TabbarController in the storyboard, jump to the identify inspector and give a storyboard ID.

Answer (score 0):

I run your code, Here is issue:

> 2018-01-18 16:23:52.845273+0800 try[8180:315334] 
>   Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

```
 self.tabBarController?.present(nav, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

this line is very wired. I seldom saw.

So you can also let a child controller of `self.tabBarController` to present `nav`.

The choose one of the tab bar.